# ng-style not applied In angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I m facing a problem using Angular.js and the ng-switch directive.

I change my style in my controller, but It's never applied In the current view... :

My current view with ng-repeat :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button" ng-repeat="chambre in spooler" ng-style="{{chambre.style}}">{{chambre.libelle}}</button>
```

My controller code :

```
$scope.spooler[id]["style"] = { 'background-color' : code_couleur  };
```

And the default controller part :

```
$scope.spooler = [{
                idt_zones : "1",
                libelle : "100",
                id_etat : 1,
                style: { 'background-color' : '#DE8C00' }
            }, {
                idt_zones : "2",
                libelle : "101",
                id_etat : 2,
                style: { 'background-color' : '#00983D' }
            }, {
                idt_zones : "3",
                libelle : "102",
                id_etat : 3,
                style: { 'background-color' : '#B9121B' }
            }];
```

When I want to change the style of an element, the background-color changes in the source code of the page, but it's never applied to the element on the view.

Weird problem
Thanks for all

Cdt

Comment: Try with `style="{{chambre.style}}"` instead of ng-style OR `ng-style="chambre.style"`

Answer (score 1):

generally you should not use the {{ }} when referring to your variables inside ng- directives (ng-click, ng-show etc)

you could change it to:

```
ng-style="chambre.style"
```

or you could put it a style tag:

```
style="{{chambre.style}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ng-style="chambre.style"`,
[See documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)